# Prove $|\int_{B}^{} f|\leq \int_{B}^{} |f|\ $ using defition of integral.

Tags: integration, inequality, definition

I'm trying to prove the below equation:

If $f: B \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $|f|$ are integrable then, $|\int_{B}^{} f|\leq \int_{B}^{} |f|\ $.

I'm trying to use the definition of integral but couldn't succeed.

Comment: Which definition of integral?

Comment: integrals have more than one definition...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any definition of integral, you have $f\leqslant g\implies\int_B f\leqslant\int_B g$ and $\int_B-f=-\int_Bf$. Therefore\begin{align}-|f|\leqslant f\leqslant|f|&\implies\int_B-|f|\leqslant\int_Bf\leqslant\int_B|f|\\&\iff-\int_B|f|\leqslant\int_Bf\leqslant\int_B|f|\\&\iff\left|\int_Bf\right|\leqslant\int_B|f|.\end{align}

Comment: I like the approach, but the two properties are not really the definition of the integral.

Comment: Jose, first of all thank you so much! Last step is still not clear to me, can you please let me know how we went to this conclusion. And I was trying to use the lower and upper sums, is this a possible way to prove?

Comment: @eldvin In the last step, all I am doing is using that fact that, if $a,b\mathbb R$ and $b\geqslant0$, then$$-b\leqslant a\leqslant b\iff|a|\leqslant b.$$If I see a way of doing this directly from the definition of the Riemann integral, I will post it here.

Comment: Say $s=\sum f(t_j)(b_j-a_j)$ is a Riemann sum for $\int_a^b f$. Then $|s|\le\sum|f(t_j)|(b_j-a_j)$, which is a Riemann sum for $\int_a^b|f|$...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Correct. You might consider posting that as an answer.

Comment: Your answer is better, because as you point out it applies to "any" integral.

Answer (score 0):

Preassume that integral $\int g$ is defined for any nonnegative measurable function $g$. This with $\int g\in[0,\infty]$ and $\int g_1+g_2=\int g_1+\int g_2$.

Function $f:B\to\mathbb R$ induces nonnegative functions $f_+:B\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto\max(f(x),0)$ and $f_-:B\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $x\mapsto\max(-f(x),0)$.

Further $f$ is measurable if and only if $f_+$ and $f_-$ are both measurable, and we have $f=f_+-f_-$ and $|f|=f_++f_-$.

$\int f$ is defined if $\int f_+<\infty$ or $\int f_-<\infty$, and if so then:$$\int f=\int f_+-\int f_-\text{ by definition! }\tag1$$

Further we have $$\int |f|=\int f_++\int f_-\tag2$$

Note that here $\int f_-$ and $\int f_+$ are nonnegative.

Then the inequality $|\int f_+-\int f_-|\leq\int f_++\int f_-$ tells us that $|\int f|\leq\int|f|$.

Comment: drhab, thank you so much. I from the definition I know that  $f=f_+-f_-$ however I didn't understand the second equation: $|f|=f_++f_-$.

Comment: It follows directly from the definition: $|a|=\max(a,0)+\max(-a,0)$ is true for every $a\in\mathbb R$.